# Constant and placeholder in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

How can I send this string "field1": "header: ${fesb.a broker.}\n const: "{{CONST}} " without any transformations, including {{VAR}}.

This code leads to the insertion of VAR property here "{{VAR}}".

```
<setBody test:component="SetBodyEndpoint">
                <constant><![CDATA["{
  "field1": "header: ${testVar}\n const: "{{VAR}}"
}"]]></constant>
 </setBody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess placeholders are getting resolved at the compile time, so you cannot have it unchanged in your route, even in `constant` expression.
As a workaround, you can put your raw string to a file and read it in the route then, e.g.

```
<setBody>
    <simple resultType="java.io.File">path/to/file/rawString.txt</simple>
</setBody>
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, the solution through file is good, but I don't like that the file is read during each processing